# How to theme the page template for search results

Tags: search, 7

I want to change the page template when displaying search results. This seems straigh forward when dealing with a content type, but what is the content type for "search results".

E.g. I'll like to use something like page--search_results.tpl.php but I'm not sure of the correct name.

Note, I'm happy with the formatted output of the result items, so I assume I wouldn't be changing the templates under drupal/modules/search...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a template, eg, `page--search.tpl.php` which would match the path to search and anything under it, eg, `search/node/term`, or you could create one called `page--search-node.tpl.php` which wouldn't match just the search page itself, but only search results from nodes, or you could use a template suggestion inside a preprocess_page() hook, eg, something like

```
mymoduleortheme_preprocess_page(&vars) {

  if (arg(0)=='search' && arg(1) && arg(2)) { // we are somewhere down in search/node/term or similar
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page_my_template_for_search_results';
  }
}
```

and then create a template file `page-my-template-for-search-results.tpl.php`.

In any case, http://drupal.org/node/1089656 has some great documentation on template suggestions in D7.

Comment: Were you using Drupal 6 or 7 when you saw this? Not sure where "args" comes from.

Comment: args? I don't follow...

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to php and wasn't sure what "arg(2)" was refering to as I can't see the variable declared in the method.

Comment: arg() is a drupal function that returns that part of the path, eg, arg(0) returns the 0th (or 1st) part, arg(1) returns the 1st (or 2nd lol) etc.  so, if your path is www.myhost.com/search, arg(0) will be search, and arg(1) will be null, as will be arg(2) since they don't exist.  but, if you are looking at www.myhost.com/search/node/term, then arg(0) will return search, arg(1) will return node and arg(2) will return term (eg, what you searched for).  so if arg(0) equals 'search' and arg(1) and arg(2) are set, you are down in the path of search results.